# Does sora cassettes wear faster than 105 cassettes

Tags: cassette

I don't know if those made of different metal. Do you know if they're made out of a different metal?

Comment: For the same number of speed (different age by about 20 years) or the same age (different number of speeds)?

Answer (score 1):

To quote https://road.cc/content/buyers-guide/head-head-shimano-tiagra-v-shimano-105-r7000-210617 on Tiagra 4700 vs. 105 7000:

> The Tiagra and 105 cassettes both feature nickel plated steel
> sprockets although the 105 version has an a spider arm and a lockring
> made from anodised aluminium and it’s considerably lighter. The
> biggest difference, though, is that a 105 cassette is 11-speed while a
> Tiagra one is 10-speed.

So in principle same material and probably similar wear characteristics.

Comment: There are also 10-speed 105 cassettes. There may be less in stock now since 105 switched to 11-speed. SRAM could be an alternative as they are fully compatible and fit the same hub.